# Intel syntax - Meaning of jmp/call instruction with $+5 operand

Tags: disassembly, x86, call, intel

I'm currently parsing a lot of assembly files and don't understand a specific `jmp` or `call` with `$+5` as operand:

```
call $+5
 jmp $+5
```

To provide more context I grepped some of the occurrences:

```
mov esp, [ebp+ms_exc.old_esp]
and [ebp+ms_exc.registration.TryLevel], 0
or [ebp+ms_exc.registration.TryLevel], 0FFFFFFFFh
call $+5
jmp sub_4493CA
===== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
push esi

[...]

mov esp, [ebp+ms_exc.old_esp]
and [ebp+ms_exc.registration.TryLevel], 0
or [ebp+ms_exc.registration.TryLevel], 0FFFFFFFFh
call $+5
jmp sub_45746A
===== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
mov eax, dword_4778F8

[...]

mov eax, ebx
test al, 2
jnz loc_100994B8
jmp $+5
-----------------------------------------------------------------
mov eax, [ebp+var_34]
mov [ebp+var_40], eax
```

What is the meaning of the `$+5` operand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

opcode for call $+5 is e8 00000000 so it calls the next instruction
opcode for jmp  $+5 is e9 00000000 so it jumps to the next insturction

```
76E95FE0                        E8 00000000 CALL    76E95FE5         ;  <ntdll.call here>
76E95FE5 <ntdll.call here>      00          DB      00
76E95FE6                        E9 00000000 JMP     76E95FEB         ;  <ntdll.jmp_here>
76E95FEB <ntdll.jmp_here>       00          DB      00
76E95FEC                        EB 02       JMP     SHORT 76E95FF0   ;  <ntdll.jmp+4>
76E95FEE                        00          DB      00
76E95FEF                        00          DB      00
76E95FF0 <ntdll.jmp+4>          00          DB      00
```

Comment: More likely E9 00 00 00 00.  EB 02 would be $+4.

Answer (score 2):

$ = Current position (beginning of the instruction)

+5 = +5 bytes from the beginning of the instruction

jmp $+5  = jmp 3 bytes past the jmp instruction (short jmp takes 2 bytes + 3 bytes past that)